# Send emails from Azure Ad User - Like noreply

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory

I have an AzureAd application and a user called noreply so I can send automated emails from my account for like password resets etc with Microsoft Graph.

Here is what I have so far:

```
string scope = _configuration["AzureAd:Scope"];
string[] scopes = { scope };
var tenantId = _configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];
var clientId = _configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
var clientSecret = _configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
      AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var requestBody = new SendMailPostRequestBody
                {
                    Message = new Message
                    {
                        Subject = "Reset Password",
                        Body = new ItemBody
                        {
                            ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                            Content = rendered
                        },
                        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
                        {
                            new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = messageDto.Email } }
                        },
                        From = new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = "noreply@myemailaddress" } }
                    }
                };

                await graphClient.Users["ObjectId"].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

This is giving me a 403 ODataError. I am using the /.default scope and in my app I have the Mail.Send scope enabled and consented for both Delegated permission and application permissions.

Anyone had to do anything similar?

Comment: `403` is not a server error. It's the html response you get for 'Access forbidden'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, you are using **client credentials flow** in your code that
> only works with **`Application`** permissions.

I registered one Azure AD application and added **`Mail.Send`** Application permission by granting consent like this:

[image]

When I ran below **modified code** in my environment, I got **response** successfully like this:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "55bc1f7b-3bc1-439e-bddd-4xxxxxxxxxx";
var tenantId = "2773f7fd-d343-4afe-8230-exxxxxxxx";
var clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail.SendMailPostRequestBody
{
    Message = new Message
    {
        Subject = "Reset Password",
        Body = new ItemBody
        {
            ContentType = BodyType.Html,
            Content = "Please reset your password soon!",
        },
        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = "sri@xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
                },
            },
        },
        From = new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = "admin@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com" } }
    },
};
await graphClient.Users["7488bc42-6a7c-4ba2-a4c3-xxxxxxxx"].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);

Console.WriteLine("Mail sent successfully!");
```

**Response:**

[image: OUTPUT SNIP]

When I checked the mailbox, mail sent successfully like below:

[image]

In your case, make sure to grant only **Application** permissions and try modifying your code as I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I did realise that in my 'From' section, my email was slightly incorrect which is what caused the 403. Once I removed the From property, it worked perfect. Thank you for your explanation though!